# how to make vortex force field like a vortex

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I use a group of object to render grass in a particles system set on hair.

Hair dynamics is on and seem to work well except that it has no bending over the stand I use.

They rotate along their origin but they do not bend. When I use the basic hair particles they do, so I assumed this is because my objects do not have segment that can be used for bending in the particle system but I did'nt find anything explaining what I need to do to achieve that.

I assume thats why the vortex force field is acting so stange because in my mind (and in nature) I don't think they'll do that (see video)

Here some screenshot for demonstrate

> the vortex force field

[image]

> The particle system

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

A view of the 3D view
[image]

and finally a render of the effect
https://youtu.be/PHE01EY38rU (sorry for the size and quality but it make foreverrrr to even do that on my computer but I think thats enough to show what I mean)